# can a procedure in oracle have ordinary select * statement inside begin and end block?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
create procedure
return(val_id int)
is
begin
    select * 
    from emp
    where emp_id = val_id;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, In Oracle you can't run ordinary SELECT statement, it's not supported.
You can do this in many other RDBMS, for example in [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#faq-mysql-can-routine-results) this works in this way:

> **A.4.14. Can MySQL 5.5 stored routines return result sets?**
>
> Stored procedures can, but stored functions cannot. If you perform an
>   ordinary SELECT inside a stored procedure, the result set is returned
>   directly to the client. You need to use the MySQL 4.1 (or higher)
>   client/server protocol for this to work. This means that, for example,
>   in PHP, you need to use the mysqli extension rather than the old mysql
>   extension.

In other words, if you run ordinary SELECT statement within a procedure, then MySql automatically creates a resultset which is then passed to the caller client.

---

In Oracle it is not done in automatic manner - you must explicitely declare a cursor and pass it as OUT parameter to the caller, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test22( val_id int, cur OUT sys_refcursor )
IS
BEGIN
  open cur for select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where empno = val_id;
END;
/
```

---

And the caller must retrieve the cursor from the parameter and handle it in explicit way, there is no any "implicit automation", for example (in SQL-Plus or SQL-Developer):

```
var ppp refcursor

exec test22( 7654, :ppp );

print ppp

     EMPNO ENAME     
---------- ----------
      7654 MARTIN
```

---

But beginning from Oracle 12.1c there is [Implicit Statement Results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-E1CD6E03-2C47-47F0-997A-DA7327739F0B) feature available which make it possible to simulate this behaviour:

> **Implicit Statement Results**
>
> Before Oracle Database 12c, a PL/SQL stored
>   subprogram returned result sets from SQL queries explicitly, through
>   OUT REF CURSOR parameters, and the client program that invoked the
>   subprogram had to bind to those parameters explicitly to receive the
>   result sets.
>
> As of Oracle Database 12c, a PL/SQL stored subprogram can return query
>   results to its client implicitly, using the PL/SQL package DBMS_SQL
>   instead of OUT REF CURSOR parameters. This technique makes it easy to
>   migrate applications that rely on the implicit return of query results
>   from stored subprograms from third-party databases to Oracle Database.
>   For more information, see "DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT Procedure" and
>   "DBMS_SQL.GET_NEXT_RESULT Procedure".

---

On Oracle 12c you can just do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test22( val_id int )
IS
  cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open cur for select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where empno = val_id;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT( cur, true );
END;
/
```

and in the client (SQL/Plus, SQL-Developer, in Java, in C# etc) you can just call this procedure, and the resultset will be automatically retrieved:

```
exec test22( 7654 );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1


     EMPNO ENAME     
---------- ----------
      7654 MARTIN
```

---

You can even return multiple resultsets to the client, an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test22( val_id int )
IS
  cur sys_refcursor;
  cur2 sys_refcursor;
  cur3 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open cur for select EMPNO, ENAME 
    from emp
    where empno = val_id;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT( cur, true );

  open cur2 for select ENAME, sal, deptno
    from emp
    where empno = val_id;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT( cur2, true );

  open cur3 for select ENAME, mgr, sal, deptno, hiredate
    from emp
    where empno = val_id;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT( cur3, true );  
END;
/
```

---

```
exec test22( 7654 );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1


     EMPNO ENAME     
---------- ----------
      7654 MARTIN    

ResultSet #2


ENAME             SAL     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
MARTIN           1250         30

ResultSet #3


ENAME             MGR        SAL     DEPTNO HIREDATE        
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
MARTIN           7698       1250         30 1981/09/28 00:00
```